# 'Host Unkown' when trying to connect to Sandbox

Tags: iri-legacy-api, sandbox

We are trying to use the sandbox to test out some functions. I get no response when I ping http://sandbox.iotatoken.com/api/v1/.

This does not work:

```
var iota = new IOTA({
  'provider': 'http://sandbox.iotatoken.com/api/v1/',
  'sandbox': true,
  'token': '162e807b-97d5-4ef6-a500-03706d859736'
});
```

We are new at this.  Is there a different sandbox address?  Is there a problem with the DNS and is there an IP address we could use?  Are we misunderstanding how to use the sandbox API?

Comment: Not every endpoint has to react to pings. That might be totally unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Where did you get your API token from? I think the sandbox changed to sandbox.iota.org some time ago, but that returns 404 now as well and since I never used the sandbox (I just used the public testnet) I have no idea whether it moved again or whether it is "just down" at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that the sandbox is up anymore or maintained. But you can just as easily play with the network by using a real node since you can send 0 value transactions. That is what I have been doing instead by just encoding value messages for testing.